# Why vbNewLine is not working?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub AutoEmail_Consultant2()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strbody As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup

    For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Payment Reminder"
                .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & "," & vbNewLine & "This email is reminder for payment of " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & " against invoice no: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & "."
                '.Send
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: In HTML Body for line break use `<br />` tag or should change to `.Body` for plain text.

Comment: Thanks Man! really appreciate your knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that you are writing HTML (you are filling the .HTMLBody property) and vbNewLine have no meaning in HTML. Use `<br/>` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You must try .Body property intead of .HTMLBody

Comment: No, the .htmlbody is correct in this case. They just need to be using the correct line break method - <br/>